# Poincaré-Bendixson applied to region enclosed by homoclinic orbit

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-dynamics

Let $p$ be a saddle point of the planar ODE $x' = f(x)$ with $f$ smooth. Suppose $\gamma$ is a homoclinic orbit starting and ending in $p$.

Define $\Gamma := \gamma \cup p$ and let $\mathcal{U}$ be the open region enclosed by $\Gamma$.

I would like to prove that $\mathcal{U}$ containts either an equilibrium point or a periodic orbit.

I thought about using the Poincaré-Bendixson theorem but I'm having trouble making it work.

I know $\Gamma \cup \mathcal{U}$ is a trapping region, but it contains the fixed point $p$. On the other hand, if I exclude $p$, the region is not closed anymore.

Am I looking in the right direction?

Edit: I am actually starting to doubt if this is even true. Isn't it possible that all trajectories starting in $\mathcal{U}$ end up in $p$?

Comment: If by saddle you mean a hyperbolic saddle, then it is impossible for all trajectories starting in $\mathcal{U}$ end in $p$. It could be so if it was an equilibrium with so called parabolic sector which is filled with trajectories homoclinic to $p$. I think that you can smooth out curve $\Gamma = \gamma \cup p$ (let's call smoothed curve $\tilde{\Gamma}$) and apply index theorem for it. I believe that index of $\tilde{\Gamma}$ should be $1$, and hence there is an equilibrium in domain enclosed by $\tilde{\Gamma}$.

Comment: I found this problem in a practice exam for an introductory course I'm taking on nonlinear dynamics. The index theorem was not part of the curriculum so I will have to look into that. I do think there might be a way to use the Poincaré-Bendixson theorem, maybe in combination with the curve Γ̃ you defined?